# aws-cli not deleting all file in folder

Tags: aws-cli

I use gitlab pipeline.
I need to upload artifacts to my build in s3.
My stage for this:

```
job:
image: python:latest
stage: upload_S3
dependencies:
    - build
before_script:
    - pip install awscli
script: 
    - aws --endpoint-url $ENDPOIN_URL s3 rm s3://$BUCKET_NAME/artifacts/ --recursive
    - aws --endpoint-url $ENDPOIN_URL s3 cp bin s3://$BUCKET_NAME/artifacts/build-$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME-$CI_PIPELINE_ID --recursive --exclude "settings*" --exclude "web.config"
only:
    changes:
        - Server/**/*
    refs:
        - master
        - /^release-.*/
when: manual
```

But when I do clear folder in s3, my delete command doesn't delete all files.
If i do this in s3Browser or retry script of clear folder in s3 - it will delete leftovers.
It accumulate in bucket.

My build have many files. Why awscli can't delete all files at once?
How I can delete all at once? (don't retry stage)

Comment: Use the following command to remove all objects without specifying a prefix, try $ aws s3 rm s3://bucket-name --recursive

Comment: or also try s3 rm s3://$BUCKET_NAME/artifacts --recursive

Comment: without prefix don't work. one month ago it's worked fine. I found a solution - replace image. In image python:3.7.7 it's work fine for me